# Show that $N(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $ H$ is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$. The normalizer of $H$ in $G$ is
$$N(H) = \{g \in G|gHg^{−1} = H\}$$
If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K \leq G$ then $K \leq N(H)$. Show that $N(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $ H$ is normal.

Can anyone give me a hit to do this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in K$.  Since $H\lhd K$, $xHx^{-1}=H$ which implies $x\in N(H)$.  Therefore $K\subseteq N(H)$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how to approach the question with your hit, can you show more details

Comment: Actually it's more than a hint, it's a proof. Because $H\lhd K$, every member of $K$ satisfies the requirement to be in $N(H)$. Perhaps you could say more about what is confusing you.

Comment: The part confuse me is what I need to show such that $H (N)$ is the largest

Comment: It has just been shown that any subgroup in which $H$ is normal must be contained in $N(H)$. So, $N(H$ is the largest such group.

Answer (score 2):

H is normal in K and K $\leq G $ 
Let $a \in K$ . 
Hence, $aH = Ha $  implies $ H = aHa^{-1} $ which implies $ a \in N(H)$.
Hence, $K\subseteq N(H) $